# TensorFlow use Spatial Transformer with given theta

Tags: tensorflow, affinetransform

I want to use the [Spatial Transformer](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/transformer) with TensorFlow without the localization net, but use a given transformation matrix theta instead. I tried the transformer with the identity matrix which should not change the input. Unfortunately this isn't the case and if I repeat the transformation on the output multiple times the image is scaled smaller and smaller into the top left corner. I thought there would be some discretization error but why for the identity transformation?

```
in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, H, W, C], name="input_image")
theta = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 6], name="input_theta")
transformed = transformer(in, theta, [H, W])
```

Comment: I think to use the transformer for manual, 'not trained' transformations it is furthermore necessary to 'inverse' the transformation, i.e. take the negative rotation angle and translation deltas because not the actual input is transformed but the 'sampling grid' G which determines the pixels sampled from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found an answer:
The problem is the use of height and width normalized coordinates, such that `-1 <= x,y <= 1`, more specifically the scaling back to matrix coordinates `0 <= x < width` and `0 <= y < height` which is done as follows in the `_interpolate` method:

```
x = (x + 1.0)*(width_f) / 2.0
y = (y + 1.0)*(height_f) / 2.0
```

Changing the `tf.linspace` functions in the `_meshgrid` method to go from `0` to `width-1` or `heigth-1` and removing the mentioned back scaling solves my problem.